# SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

When running a query that join data from 3 large tables I’m getting an error that says

```
   The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can simply issue a query containing the SET command:

```
 $this->db->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');
```

Comment: I upvote this as correct answer, i just added some extra information in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you have to big selects. As Faizan says, you can set the SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 in the config file or define the global variable in a active session (no restart needed of the service).

Also, have a look at this documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_join_size. Its good to understand the effect of the parameters. Maybe your inital select is not optimized for desired result. Just a extra thought.